# How to fetch data from webserver before activity oncreated or started in android program?

Tags: android

In my activity there are several params which are used for showing user infomation  such as user scores. However, the score is   got from webserver and changed every 5 minutes. So i make a invisible refresh button  and performClick it every 5 minutes to fetch data from webserver. I use asynctask to do http work. But how to initiate activity when it is first shown? As the activity is onresumed, it is post forground, and theasynctask thread is not completed,so no user information available.Ijust want to fetch data before activity started or oncreated.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `Service`, and run it on a timer.

EDIT: much longer write up than makes sense here, but take a look at [this](http://dhimitraq.wordpress.com/2012/11/27/using-intentservice-with-alarmmanager-to-schedule-alarms/).

Answer (score 0):

You can do one thing using the application run display the splash screen at that time fetch record from web server using asyntask and than set to global arraylist and display that when you needed